# VB.NET byte <-> string conversion error/problem

Tags: vb.net

I am reading data from a socket (as bytes) and storing this data in a string. Then later i need to access specific bytes within the string and do some math with them. However the bytes that I read back from the string are not what I am expecting.

Here's code to demonstrate my problem:

```
    Dim bytTest() As Byte = {131, 0}
    Dim strTest As String
    strTest = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytTest)
    MsgBox(bytTest(0) & " = " & Asc(strTest.Substring(0, 1)))
```

This produces "131 = 63", but I would have expected it to produce "131 = 131". Can somebody explain to me why and how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to convert the bytes to a string?

Comment: I think he is composing a string in ASCII encoding out of the received bytes.

Comment: I realized that the bytes were converted into an ASCII string (the code is rather clear on that point). My question was rather; why do you need to convert the bytes to an ASCII string if you later intend to use the bytes as such for calculations? Wouldn't it make more sense to keep the data as bytes and convert to strings when (and if) needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII encoding only uses the lower 7 bits of a byte for each character. Thus, if you pass a byte with value 131 to it, you will get unexpected results, since the high bit is set for that value.

Answer (score 1):

ASCIIEncoding is limited to the first 7 bits (characters 0-127), so trying to store character with a value of 131 isn't going to work as expected.

Use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: no need for UTF-8, all i needed was System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) instead of ASCII